# Using Google's fullname in an Android app

Tags: android, reporting, account, privacy

I developed an app which allows the user to report not collected poos in a remote database: if you give consent to the app, you can report the poo with your Google's fullname (which it's hold and encrypted in a private database), otherwise you will report it anonimously. (In the reporting page i ask if the user wants to utilize his real name).

The user who gave the permission to use his name in the reporting and who made more reportings than the other users can obtain the title of "King of reportings", and his name will be shown in a statistics page, like this one.

[image]

My question is: is legal to utilize the user Google account's fullname, even if I asked him to use it, or can i have some issues for it?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: In my opinion, it is legal to use user's personal information after when the user gives permission, which is obvious on android platform. On the other side, you can show a little information about how you are using his or her name in your application for more clarity. Then again if you are doing any illegal work by his or her personal info, you are all good!

Comment: Before the repoting, I specify that his/her name will be hold in a Firebase database, and that I encrypt it. So, neither me and no other one can see the user's fullname in the database, the only time when it is visible is when the users got the title of "The king of reportings"!

Comment: Questions about legal issues would be better suited for [law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Upvoted just for poos!

Comment: Thank you Synchro!